# How can I change image with opacity transition in response to an onClick event using CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to  change image with opacity transition in response to an onClick event using CSS3 without using of any javascript framework.

Here is my code which change the image but without opacity transition.

```
#cf img.imgClass {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

<_div id="cf">
    <_img  id='imgId' src='photos/IMG_0290.JPG'>
</_div>

```
(function ( ) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onclick = function () {
        return function () {
            var imgSrc = document.getElementById('imgId').src;
            (imgSrc.indexOf('IMG_0288.JPG') > 0) ? imgSrc = 'photos/IMG_0290.JPG' : imgSrc = 'photos/IMG_0288.JPG'; 
            document.getElementById('imgId').src = imgSrc;
            document.getElementById('imgId').className = "imgClass";
        }
    }();
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following javascript function it works, 
but it will be possibile just using css?

If yes, how?

```
function fade (id) {
    var dom = document.getElementById(id),
        level =1,
        step = function (){
            var h = level.toString(10);
            dom.style.opacity = h / 10;
            if (level < 10) {
                level += 1;
                setTimeout(step, 100);
            }
        }
    step();
}
fade('cf');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#cf img.imgClass {opacity on css}
#cf img.imgClass:hover {opacity off css}
```

Comment: I don't want to apply the transaction effect during the hover state but in response to an onClick event.